# Is it possible to create a managed JAX-WS dispatch client?

Tags: java, web-services, jax-ws

Does anyone know if it is possible to create a Dispatch dynamic webservice client in JAX-WS which could be managed by the application server? The reason for asking is because we'd like to configure policies on the client from the admin console at deployment time.

The only way I've managed to get service clients to be noticed by an application server is when I create clients based on SEI classes generated from WSDL's.

Im running Websphere Application 7.

Answer (score 0):

WS in Message level, I had some issues solved right now. With message level handling you will be able to handle incoming request in one place, from there you can dispatch messages anywhere.

If i was thinking stg else than you, please forgive me. Look at the question: 
[Message level Jax-WS service](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5181194/message-level-jax-ws-service)