# Message level Jax-WS service

Tags: java, web-services, spring, jax-ws

I'm trying to create a WebService stub. I like to react to all of the request in one single place. I have a sample value generator, which handles the type of the request and creates a sample response, so I don't need the code-generation things with a lots of classes. Only a really simple one.

I have found http://jax-ws.java.net/nonav/2.2.1/docs/provider.html WebServiceProvider which is exactly for getting raw SOAP messages, and create a response in a single place.

The main problem is I'm new to this magical EE world :) and I simply can not start WebServiceProvider sample anyway.

I have Spring, SpringSource ToolSuit, Axis installed/configured, all of the other things are working.

Thank you all for your help, and please excuse me if the question is too simple for you. Maybe I just did not find/read something.
M.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finally I have found the solution (thanks for the help from my workmates).
If you are using JAX-WS, there is a simple solution.

You need a sun-jaxws.xml in your WEB-INF folder containing the following:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<endpoints xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/jax-ws/ri/runtime" version="2.0">
  <endpoint
     name="RawWS"
     implementation="com.stg.pack.MyServiceProvider"

     url-pattern="/HotelServices200631"/>
</endpoints>
```

And you need a com.stg.pack.MyServiceProvider class which looks like:

```
package com.stg.pack;

@ServiceMode(value = Service.Mode.MESSAGE)
@WebServiceProvider(portName = "ThePortNameOfWebService", 
        serviceName = "TheNameOfWebService", 
        targetNamespace = "http://www.example.com/target/namespace/uri")
public class MyServiceProvider implements Provider<SOAPMessage> {

    @Override
    public SOAPMessage invoke(SOAPMessage request) {
        SOAPMessage result = null;
        // create response SOAPMessage
        return result;
    }
}
```

And before I forget, you need to define some things in web.xml:

```
   <listener>
     <listener-class>
        com.sun.xml.ws.transport.http.servlet.WSServletContextListener
     </listener-class>
   </listener>
   <servlet>
      <servlet-name>RawWS</servlet-name>
      <servlet-class>
        com.sun.xml.ws.transport.http.servlet.WSServlet
      </servlet-class>

   </servlet>
   <servlet-mapping>
     <servlet-name>RawWS</servlet-name>
     <url-pattern>/TheNameOfWebService</url-pattern>
   </servlet-mapping>
```

If you use it like this, all of the request are handled by the invoke method.

Answer (score 0):

you basically must deploy your provider to some sort of Container. developing in J/EE basically mandates that you compile some sort of EAR or WAR or JAR and tell an app server to deploy it (be that app server a JBOSS, glassfish, Weblogic, Websphere, Tomcat, etc).

Have you tried doing this?

it also may be possible to test your provider using the javax.xml.ws.Endpoint class, although I have to admit I've never chosen to per-sue this in favor of deploying to an app server.